# Generalization of the inequality $(n_{1}+n_{2})^2<2(n_{1}^2+n_{2}^2)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have proved that $(n_{1}+n_{2})^2<2(n_{1}^2+n_{2}^2)$ as follows:

$(n_{1}+n_{2})^2+(n_{1}^2-n_{2}^2)^2=2(n_{1}^2+n_{2}^2)$

i.e., $(n_{1}+n_{2})^2<2(n_{1}^2+n_{2}^2)$

A direct generalization of it seems to be look like:

$(n_1+n_2+\cdot \cdot\cdot+n_t)^t <a(n_{1}^t+n_{2}^t+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{t}^t)$

Where $t$ is a fixed natural number and $a$ is any constant. Any hint or explicit proof, even for the basic cases, when $t=3,4$ would be a great help.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Comment: For any $t>1$ convexity of $x \to x^{t}$ applied to $\frac { \sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}n_i^{t}} t$ will give such an inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks a lot!

Comment: @fwd, thanks a lot!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, as a convex function satisfy $f(tx_{1}+(1-t)x_{2})\leq tf(x_{1})+(1-t)f(x_{2})$, so as per your hint I will take point $x_{1}$ as you suggested but what value for $x_2$ I need to take to conlude the proof.

Comment: @Manojupreti We also have $f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2+...+t_nx_n) \leq t_1f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)+...+t_nf(x_n)$ whe $t_i \geq 0$ and $\sum t_i=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks a lot!

Comment: The absolute $<$ relationship in the first case is false when $n_1=n_2$. So either you must specify $n_1\ne n_2$, or use the relationship $\le$.

Comment: @KeithBackman, thank you.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks for your idea. It proved to be useful for us, we need to site this result in a generalized research paper. Can you please tell me if this is a well-known result or your own idea we will site accordingly?